# Program to find Standard deviation, average and sum using call by reference in C language

Tags: pointers, standard-deviation

So this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void calculateSD(float *data,float *standardDeviation, float *sum, float *average)
{
int i;

for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    *sum= *sum+data[i];
}
*average = *sum/10;
for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    *standardDeviation += pow(data[i] - *average, 2);   
}
*standardDeviation=*standardDeviation/10;
}
    int main()
{
int i;
float average=0.0;
float SD=0.0;
float sum=0.0;
float *standardDeviation=&SD;
float *psum=&sum;
float *paverage=&average;
float *data=(float*)calloc(5,sizeof(float));

printf("Enter 5 elements: ");
for(i=0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    scanf("%f",&data[i]);   
}
calculateSD(data,standardDeviation,psum,paverage);

printf("\nStandard Deviation = %f", SD);
printf("\nAverage= %f", average);
printf("\nSum= %f",sum);

return 0;
}
```

I dont know whats wrong with this. I am getting the sum and average as some garbage value.

And StandardDeviation is equal to zero.

**I have to use Call by reference so no return statement**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array size is 5

```
float *data=(float*)calloc(5,sizeof(float));
```

but when you traverse it in the function you're giving 10 as its size

```
for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    *sum= *sum+data[i];
}
```

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks